# If we want to give the apps fake geolocation datas is it enough to change only the GPS data or i need to change all datas that are transsmitted?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, operating-system

When we change the GPS data using fake GPS app the cell id of our BTS still shows completely different region (the region of our real location). Isn't that enough for third-party applications to understand  that the received Gps datas are fake ? We know that most of positioning systems using hybrid thechnologies for positioning and not a specefic one .In this case if we want to give the third party apps  fake datas  is it enough to change only the GPS data or i need to change all datas that are transsmitted (Gsm,wi fi, ect.)

Comment: You might want to explain what "BTS" means. Also is this GPS spoofing for testing or anti-piracy/fraud measures?

Comment: @MorrisonChang  BTS means Base Stations . For testig.